# java.lang.IllegalAccessException: is related to public / private attribute for classes?

Tags: java, exception

I get the following error in my Java code:

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class org.apache.commons.digester.ObjectCreateRule can not access a member of class Response with modifiers ""
```

Is it maybe because class Response is not public class ?
If so, how can I make it accessible and keep the class Response in the same file with the main class ?

thanks

Update, Code: http://www.smipple.net/snippet/aneuryzma/on:%20is%20related%20to%20public%20/%20private%20attribute%20for%20classes%20%3F

Comment: What do you mean, "the main class"?

Comment: Can you post the code that causes this exception?

Comment: Why does Response need to be in the same file as the main class?

Comment: @Pointy @StackOverflowException @justkt  I've added the code to the question. For main class I mean the public class having the same name of the file. I would prefer to keep all my classes in the same file if possible.

Comment: Don't keep all your classes in the same file. That's a terrible idea.

Comment: Make sure your package naming in the .java files matches the directory structure of your source tree (and the resulting tree of .class files).

Comment: @Pointy I hadn't include the local folder in the classpath. I've solved by creating multiple files and having public classes only. Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As far as I remember your class Response should follow the bean convention: should be public, should have public default constructor and should have setters and getters for all fields that you refer from your xml.

Answer (score 6):

Yes it is, as [IllegalAccessException documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalAccessException.html) says.

You can circumvent access modifiers with reflection. For example, to access private fields, use `Class.getDeclaredField(String)` to get a specific `Field` (works also for private fields - using plain `getField` can only get public members), and then set `Field.setAccessible(true)`. Now the field can be used as if it was public.

You can also circumvent access modifier with [JNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface). It doesn't care about access modifiers at all. Yet one more way is to generate custom bytecode with a tool such as [ASM](http://forge.ow2.org/projects/asm).

Comment: It is fine and right, but he receives the exception from digester. I do not believe that he wants to modify it.

Comment: Humm, true, if `Response` is is own class, of course he probably should fix the problem by making it public.

Answer (score 1):

> can not access a **member** of class Response with **modifiers** ""

A **member** is an instance variable, modifiers are `public`, `protected`, `static`, ...

So it looks to me, that the `Response` class has a field that can't be accessed or created through the apache-commons-digesters ObjectCreationRule.

Either you have a `Response` class that is not compatible with digester or the error lies within the xml file that defines the `Response` class.

---

Looking at your code - the only Java "items" with no access modifiers are the classes `Response` and `Request`. Maybe the error tells us that those classes have to be public.

Answer (score 0):

ObjectCreateRule attempts uses the loads Request via it's class name and then invokes Class.newInstance(). For this to work the Request and Response both need public and have public default constructors.

You have two options for this:
 1. Place Request and Response in their own source files and make them public
 2. Nest Request and Response inside your public top level class and make them `public static`.

If you took option two then your code would look like this:
    import java.io.Reader;
    import java.io.StringReader;

```
import org.apache.commons.digester.Digester;

public class DigExample {

    public static void main(String ar[]) {
        try {
            Digester digester = new Digester();
            digester.setValidating( false );

            digester.addObjectCreate( "response", Response.class );

            digester.addObjectCreate( "response/request", Request.class );
            digester.addBeanPropertySetter("response/request/name", "name" );
            digester.addBeanPropertySetter("response/request/value", "value" );
            digester.addSetNext( "response/request", "setRequest" );

            digester.addBeanPropertySetter( "response/matches", "matches" );

            Reader reader = new StringReader(
                            "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>" + 
                            "<response>" + 
                            "<request><name>books</name><value>xml</value></request>" +  
                            "<matches>20</matches>" + 
            "</response>");
            Response response = (Response)digester.parse( reader );

            System.out.println( response.toString() );

        } catch( Exception exc ) {
            exc.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    static  public  class Response {

        public Response(){}

        private int _matches = 0;
        private Request  _request;

        public Request getRequest() {
            return _request;
        }

        public void setRequest(Request request) {
            _request = request;
        }

        public int getMatches() {
            return _matches;
        }

        public void setMatches(int matches) {
            _matches = matches;
        }

    }



    static public class Request {

        public Request() {}

        private String _name = "";
        private String _value = "";

        public String getName() {
            return _name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            _name = name;
        }

        public String getValue() {
            return _value;
        }

        public void setValue(String value) {
            _value = value;
        }

    }
}
```

As other people have mentioned, if you were using reflection directly yourself you could probably circumvent the access modifiers, but this isn't an option in your example.