# I want to load new FXML file with some parameters from the other Controller Files

Tags: java, constructor, javafx, fxml

I already read next answers about passing parameters, but they didn't help me.

- [passing-parameters-javafx-fxml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187963/passing-parameters-javafx-fxml)
- [javafx-from-the-trenches-singleton-controllers](http://ed4becky.net/homepage/javafx-from-the-trenches-singleton-controllers/)

Below is my effort to open new FXML view from event handler which failes to pass parameter.

Kindly looking for help.

**MainController.java**

```
@FXML
private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) throws IOException 
{

    Context currentContext = new Context();
    URL url = getClass().getResource("ManageTemplateChild.fxml");
    FXMLLoader fxmlloader = new FXMLLoader();
    fxmlloader.setLocation(url);
    fxmlloader.setBuilderFactory(new JavaFXBuilderFactory());
    bordermanagetemp.getChildren().clear();
    bordermanagetemp.getChildren().add((Node) fxmlloader.load(url.openStream()));

    ((ManageTemplateChildController) fxmlloader.getController())
         .setContext(currentContext,Finalvaluetablerow);
}
```

**ManageTemplateChildController.java**

```
private Context context;
public void setContext(Context context,Object Finalvaluetablerow)
{
    this.context = context;
    o = Finalvaluetablerow;
    System.out.println("value of main" + Finalvaluetablerow + " value of child" + o);
    testlabel.setText((String) o);
}
```

**Context.java**

```
public class Context {
    private final static Context instance = new Context();

    public static Context getInstance() {
        return instance;
    } 
}
```

**ManageTemplateChild.FXML**

```
<!-- language: xml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>

<BorderPane fx:id="bordernew" prefHeight="497.0" prefWidth="642.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/2.2" fx:controller="customercloudfx.ManageTemplateChildController">
  <center>
    <AnchorPane prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0">
      <children>
        <Label fx:id="testlabel" layoutX="153.0" layoutY="168.0" text="Label">
          <font>
            <Font size="100.0" />
          </font>
        </Label>
      </children>
    </AnchorPane>
  </center>
</BorderPane>
```

This code correctly opens new `Pane` but throws next exception. Also `Label` in the child pane is not shown.

NPE comes from next line: 
    bordermanagetemp.getChildren().add((Node) fxmlloader.load(url.openStream()));

**StackTrace:**

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1440)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:69)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:217)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:170)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:38)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:37)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:53)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:28)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:171)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:6863)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:179)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:193)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.SkinBase$4.handle(SkinBase.java:336)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.SkinBase$4.handle(SkinBase.java:329)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:64)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:217)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:170)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:38)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:37)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:53)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:33)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:171)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3324)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3164)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1900(Scene.java:3119)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1559)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2261)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:228)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:528)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:922)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication$3$1.run(GtkApplication.java:82)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1435)
    ... 44 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement can not access a member of class customercloudfx.ManageTemplateChildController with modifiers ""
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processValue(FXMLLoader.java:661)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:572)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2314)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2131)
    at customercloudfx.ManageTemplateController.handleButtonAction(ManageTemplateController.java:127)
    ... 49 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement can not access a member of class customercloudfx.ManageTemplateChildController with modifiers ""
    at sun.reflect.Reflection.ensureMemberAccess(Reflection.java:95)
    at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.slowCheckMemberAccess(AccessibleObject.java:261)
    at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkAccess(AccessibleObject.java:253)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.doSecurityCheck(Field.java:983)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.getFieldAccessor(Field.java:927)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Field.java:680)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processValue(FXMLLoader.java:659)
    ... 53 more
```

Comment: What does this have to do with [tag:Swing]?

Comment: @AndrewThompson: that's why you downvote me?

Comment: At over 600 rep. and identifying yourself as a `Swing-FX2GURU` you should know a) Not to slap tags on posts just because you feel like it. b) The difference between Swing and Java-FX.

Comment: *"..but be gentle!"*  Learn from your mistakes and take better care in future.

Comment: If you *Learn from your mistakes and take better care in future* I won't need to.  Not that I ***would*** 'be gentle'..  A poor question should be down-voted to warn others that might mistake it for good information.  Fail to do that, and the signal to noise ratio plummets.

Comment: who downvoted me? and why?

Comment: @Swing-FX2GURU, you need to also post your fxml. Or refer to [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5105289/java-lang-illegalaccessexception-is-related-to-public-private-attribute-for-c) for hint.

Comment: @UlukBiy: I update my question with FXML file!!

Comment: @Swing-FX2GURU, Is ManageTemplateChildController class public? Check are the private "fx:id" fields (bordernew and testlabel) have "@ FXML" annotations in front of? Or simply make them public if @ FXML does not exist.

Comment: @Swing-FX2GURU, you are welcome, happy codings!

Comment: @Uluk Biy, please, post your finding as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception says that the `FXMLLoader` cannot access to your ManageTemplateChildController class itself or to its fields/methods through reflection. Make your class public. Add `@FXML` annotation to private fields which are defined in FXML file as "fx:id", or alternatively make these fields public without adding @FXML annotation.

Comment: I accept your answer as its my solution!! Thanks again!!

Answer (score 1):

The link that you have provided has everything in it. It is one of the best answers for those who have doubts on `How to pass data between Controllers` and *an answer to your question as well !*

But, in your case, I would **suggest** to use `Binding` inside of passing parameters ! You can have a `id` in your `ChildController` and you can just bind it to the `MainController's id`. So that the value of `id` is automatically passed between the controllers

You can have a look at the following URL for a better understanding or if you can show, how you getting the id in MainController, may be I can help you with some code !

http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/binding/jfxpub-binding.htm

http://www.drdobbs.com/jvm/javafx-20-binding/231903245

**EDIT** - *To load controller from FXML*

```
@FXML
private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) throws IOException 
{
         //Instead of making a reference from the FXMLLoader, you are creating a new Object
         //ManageTemplateChildController m = new ManageTemplateChildController();
         //try using
         FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("ManageTemplateChild.fxml"));
         ManageTemplateChildController controller = 
                          loader.<ManageTemplateChildController>getController();
         //where loader is the FXMLLoader for you second FXML
         m.redirecthome(stage,Finalvaluetablerow);
}
```

Comment: I passed parameter succesfully but could not get open that FXML file.. so how to load that FXML file?

Comment: it gives me nullpointer exception at `ManageTemplateChildController controller = 
                          loader.<ManageTemplateChildController>getController();` line?

Comment: Did you load your `loader` using fxml file ?

Comment: where to mention FXML file? this line `FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("ManageTemplateChild.fxml"));` need to add? or how? I don't know as I am new to javaFX!!

Comment: I have updated my answer, mind it that your `FXML` must have controller defined in it !

Comment: now this line `controller.redirecthome(stage,Finalvaluetablerow);` gets nullpointer!!

Comment: I can't be there! as I am restricted! so can you give solution to @capdroid.. as he is my senior?

Comment: I can't give solution, we need to discuss things ! There are things that you have to learn, he must not !